# Question about open mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let, $f:\Omega\to \mathbb C$ be a non constant anlytic function on an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb C$.For $r>0$ let $\mathbb D_r=\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|<r\}$ and let $\bar{ \mathbb D_r}$ be its closure. Which of the followings are true ?

(A) If  $\bar{ \mathbb D_1}\subset f(\Omega)$ then $\mathbb D_r\subset f(\Omega)$ for some $r>1$.

(B) If $\bar{ \mathbb D_1}\subset f(\Omega)$ then $\mathbb D_r= f(\Omega)$ for some $r>1$.

(C) If $\bar{ \mathbb D_1}\subset f(\Omega)$ then $\bar{\mathbb D_r}\subset f(\Omega)$ for some $r>1$.

(D) $f(\Omega)$ is open.

As, $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb C$ , so by open mapping theorem $f(\Omega)$ is open. So, option (D) is true.

But I have no idea about the other options.

Please help...

Comment: The open mapping theorem applies only to open connected sets. So, I think you need to look into that as well.

Comment: BTW, where did you find this question ?

Comment: It is question from a national level examination of India.

Comment: In fact I am not able to understand your answer..

Answer (score 1):

First note that (A) and (C) are equivalent.

The implication “(C) ⇒ (A)” is trivial, and the other direction “(A) ⇒ (C)” is almost trivial: If $\mathbb D_r ⊂ f(Ω)$, then for $r’ = r/2$, you have $\overline{\mathbb D_{r’}} ⊂ \mathbb D_r$.

For (B), take a very trivial map $ℂ → ℂ$ and restrict it to a non-disc shape $Ω$ containing $\overline{\mathbb D_1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Option b** : We can give a counter example , $\Omega= {|z|<2} $  union  $  |z-10|<1$ (not connected) with $f(z)= z$. So, this works only because we don't need to have the domain to be connected. 
**Option d** : If the domain is not connected, then we could have a function that gives different constants on the different components as a counterexample. 
 If the domain is connected, then we apply the open mapping theorem to imply that it is true. 
**Option a and c** : ( Since thay are equivalent as mentioned in another answer )  
**Suppose $f(\Omega)$ is open.** We have that the closed unit disc is contained in it. For every point on the boundary, there is an open disc centred at that point which lies completely inside $f(\Omega)$. The collection of all such open discs is an open cover for the boundary $|z|=1$. Since this is compact, this open cover has a finite cover. From the finite cover (which is a finite number of open discs) choose the radius of the smallest disc. This radius works for every point on the boundary. From here we can conclude that a ( and therefore c ) are true.

Comment: As $\mathbb D_2 ⊂ Ω = f(Ω)$, this isn’t a counterexample to (A) and (C).

Comment: Thanks . I edited it. What do you think about options A and C ? They are equivalent as you have proved. I'm not able to come up with any counterexample.

Comment: I think they are both true in general, but I’m kind of too lazy to prove it right now. I thought it’d work with the Lebesgue’s number lemma, but I’m not sure about that anymore.